# How to wire MenuItem Command to a Custom Command and Methods on the View

Tags: c#, wpf, events, command

I had a simple TextBlock on a View that I added a ContextMenu for.  I wanted to wire the Command for the MenuItem to execute a method on the View.  After the better part of the day I found only one working solution which leads me to believe I am missing something.  There are so many things that just aren't making sense to me.

This is the only way I could get this to work.

```
<TextBlock Text="Test">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Test Me" Command="w:Command.TestMe" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>

public static class Command
{
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand TestMe= new RoutedUICommand("Test Me", "TestMe", typeof(MainWindow));
}
```

In MainWindow class:

```
    public MainWindow()
    { 
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(Command.EditAlarm, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(EditAlarmDetails), new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(CanEditAlarm)));
        InitializeComponent();

        Focus();
    }
    public void CanTestMe(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    public void TestMeDetails(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestView view = new TestView();
        view.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Why is it when I had the CommandBindings Declared in the XAML I finally got it to work but the MenuItem was always disabled?

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="w:Command.TestMe" Executed="TestMeDetails" CanExecute="CanTestMe" /> 
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Why wasn't I able to just declare a RelayCommand and reference like I normally would from a ViewModel?

```
public ICommand TestCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (testCommand == null)
                testCommand = new RelayCommand(param => TestMeDetails(), param => CanTestMe());

            return changeStatusCommand;
        }
    } 

public bool CanTestMe()
{
    return true;
}

public void TestMeDetails() { }
```

Why does the RoutedUICommand Class have to be a in a seperate Static class to work but have a typeof(MainWindow) instead of the static instance of itself typeof(Command)?  There must be a piece of this that I am not understanding.  Surely it can't be this convoluted to wire up a simple command event to a button or element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally **`ICommand`** are supposed to stay in ViewModel but in case you want to create that in code behind of Window, you can achieve that as well *(without creating RoutedCommand)*.

You can bind with command like you do in ViewModel but before that you need to consider these cases.

1. **ContextMenu doesn't lie in same visual tree of the control where it is applied over.** So, to do bindings with parent window you have to use **`PlacementTarget`**.
2. Once you get placement target you can do binding with code behind like you do for any command in ViewModel.

This code will work:

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Text="Test"
            Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                     AncestorType=Window}}">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Test Me"
                      Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.TestCommand, 
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                  AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

*Notice, I have placed window in Tag and accessed from MenuItem using PlacementTarget.*

**Code behind**

```
private ICommand testCommand;
public ICommand TestCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (testCommand == null)
            testCommand = new RelayCommand(param => TestMeDetails(),
                                           param => CanTestMe());

        return testCommand;
    }
}

public bool CanTestMe()
{
    return true;
}

public void TestMeDetails() { }
```

Comment: I saw the edit to the Title.  Should I be leaving off language specific identifiers in my titles?  If so I will make sure I do from now on.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah tags are there for that purpose. Also, any reason for not accepting this as an answer if it solves your issue?

Comment: Please forgive my manners and accept my apology.  I had thought I had accepted the answer and added a thank you previously but I may have added it to a different thread.  Your answer was correct and greatly helped to get me on track!  I geniunely appreciate your answer and the explanation behind it.  Thank you!